# React-Native Timer Recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, react-native

I'm building React-Native Weather app. My problem is, I need to keep data up to date, and I don't know how. Docs aren't actually describing (or i haven't found) how app behaves while working as a background process.

I simply need to make series of HTTP requests every ~3 hours (forecast API), and I'm wondering if setTimeout() or setInterval() is good idea here. Would they work while app runs on the background? I got worried even more, after I've found [BackgroundJob](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job) library for RN. And it's not supported by iOS.

Question is: should I use setTimeout(), setInterval(), or any kind of cronjob* library? Or what's the best alternative?

Comment: Have you considered websockets?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: yes, I have. Although this would require me to keep track of all the users, their chosen locations. Saying shortly, instead of having "bridge api" (in order to protect the key) I'd have to get redis or mongo database, to keep track of unnecessary data. But if I won't find the solution, I might try them

Comment: why doesn't the clients just send the server their location in the message sent? The websocket server can then act as a proxy holding onto the api key and making another http request with the client's location and returning the response back to the client

Comment: that is actually valid point. Server could speak up to the client with data it needs, and client would get parse that data back. Maybe thats even better than REST API bridge :D

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: but questions that comes now is: are websockets allowed to run on the background on iOS? And if so, is Apple allowing for constant connections with the server? I've heard they reject such apps, if that's not audio streaming or VOIP app